# How K-Fold Cross-Validation will help in avoiding consumption of training data set?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, overfitting, validation

One way of hyperparameter tuning is to try different values on validation test, suppose we divide the data into training(60%), validation(20%) and test(20%) set. 
Here disadvantage is we are eating up the training data set by dividing it into one extra set(validation set).

I read that Cross-Validation can be used to avoid this data consumption(by having dedicated extra validation set).

Now in Cross-Validation, we divide the data into only training and test set and suppose we divide the dataset as training(80%) and test(20%).

And we again divide the training data into multiple folds(let's take folds=4) from which we create multiple models(per iteration) and test the models on one of the fold.

Single iteration will look like - F1(20%) F2(20%) F3(20%) F4(20%), 
Essentially model will be trained on 3 folds(60%) and tested on 1 fold(20%), again we are training our model in 60% of data then how we are avoiding eating up more data here?

I think I am missing something here because as per my understanding I don't see cross-validation helping in avoiding more consumption of training data.

Comment: if you do 4 fold, it's training on 75% and testing on 25%, you can see diagram here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459913/k-folds-cross-validation-is-it-necessary-to-randomize-the-training-set-before-s

Comment: 75% of 80 = 60% of 100,  but I got it,  I got confused because I took folds as 4 and in this case, model will eventually train on the same amount of data. But if you took more than 4 folds then more training data will be available.